# Create JPA Projection into the same repository

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, projection, jpa-2.1

I want to create this JPA Projection:

```
@Repository
public interface PaymentTransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<PaymentTransactions, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<PaymentTransactions> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT count(id) as count, status, error_class, error_message, id FROM " +
            " payment_transactions " +
            " WHERE terminal_id = :id AND (created_at > :created_at) "      List<PaymentTransactionsDeclineReasonsDTO> transaction_decline_reasons(@Param("id") Integer transaction_unique_id, @Param("created_at") LocalDateTime created_at);
}
```

Class based Projection DTO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class PaymentTransactionsDeclineReasonsDTO {

    private Integer id;

    private Integer count;

    private String status;

    private String error_class; 

    private String error_message;

}
```

But I get exception

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [org.plugin.service.PaymentTransactionsDeclineReasonsDTO]
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue? I suppose that I have to create a separate repository `extends JpaRepository<PaymentTransactionsDeclineReasonsDTO, Integer>`?

But I would like to use the same repository because I have queries which use the proper entity. Is there some solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with a normal projection as an interface.
[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections) you can find a good tutorial of how to set up an interface based projection.
Basically you would convert your `PaymentTransactionsDeclineReasonsDTO` to an interface and declare the getters you want to access through your projection:

```
public interface PaymentTransactionsDeclineReasonsDTO {
    int getId();
    int getCount();
    //... and so on
}
```

This way you can still use the same repository but only get selected properties of your actual class.